# How to solve "error 000816: The tool is not valid" with ET Geowizards tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arctoolbox, et-geowizards, error-000816

I have installed ET Geowizards 11.2 for ArcGIS 10.3 using setup.exe and followed the instructions. I am using ArcGIS 10.3.

I can use ET Geowizards tools from the toolbar and I can run them in ModelBuilder. However, I cannot run them from the toolbox. When I load the ET Geowizard.tbx into the ArcToolbox and run a tool, I get the following error:

[image]

According to online resource http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/ToolBox/toolbox_howto_load.htm the tools get registred in the installation. However, this doesn't appear to have been succesful.

My questions is how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

ET support provided the answer:

If the machine on which you are running ArcGIS 10.1 has 64 Bit Windows and you have installed the Background Geoprocessing for the toolbox implementation of the ET GeoWizards functionality will fail if executed in Background. The reason for this is that ArcGIS (if installed on a 64 Bit machine) pushes the geoprocessing tasks to 64 Bit Python. Currently ET GeoWizards is a 32 Bit application that runs with no problem on 64 Bit computers, but in 32 bit mode.

If you execute the functions via the ET GeoWizards interface they should run just fine

If you are executing the tools from ArcToolbox, you need to untick the box in the Geoprocessing Options that enables Background Geoprocessing.

If you are using Python scripts, you need to run them using 32 Bit Python. There should be two versions of Python
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe - 32 bit
or
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\python.exe - 64 bit
make sure to run Python.exe with the full path - C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe

Comment: I confirm the solution found by user3811338, in a different context. Some arcToolbox tools generate ERROR 00816 when called up by default with 64-bits python, and work fine when called-up by 32-bits python. I observed this with metadata tools (conversion toolbox).

Comment: Fantastic. I was receiving the same error with a python script working with the arcpy.ImportMetadata_conversion tool. I forced the script to run in 32 bit python and it now executes correctly.